# Auto Fill Text field from one text field to another with small change

Tags: html, django

Is there anyway to auto populate fields based on user input from the 1 text field, then update rest of the fields with small changes in each field.

For example:

```
[user input] Field 1 Network: 192.168.0.0 
[auto] Field 2 Network_Util: 192.168.1.0
[auto] Field 3 Network_Util2: 192.168.2.0
```

I tried to for following code, but it copies the text, how to change the third octet value?

```
<input type="text"id="network1" name="Network1" value="" >
<input type="text" id="network2" name="Network2" value="">

$("#network1").keyup(function(){
    var net = network1.split(".");
    var octet3 = net[2];
    $("#network2").val(this.value);
});
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function :

```
$("#network1").keyup(function(){
    var net = this.value.split(".");
    if (net.length > 2) net[2] = 'new';
    $("#network2").val(net.join('.'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but doesn't change the value next field http://jsfiddle.net/Lfbra9xm/

Comment: you mean the third field  ?

Comment: How to get the last item in the list in ajax, splitting up the name. example: hostname1 >> hostname2 ? `var hostname = $("#hostname1").val(net[-1] + 1);`

Comment: this could be another question, you can use `net.pop()` if you only want to deal with the last item (will be remove from the list), or `net[net.length-1]` to access the element inside the array.

Comment: (btw, this is not ajax, only javascript with the library jQuery, ajax is the logic used when you perform request to the server through javascript)